Edit remote path on remote ssh tunnel vscode connection
I am using vs code on Windows 11 and have remote tunnel connection to vscode server that works fine but i want to change the path I am placed in once I connect to the remote code.  The remote server is Ubuntu 24 on a PI 5 machine.
Is there a way to change the remote path I land in?
Thanks

In VSCode, I think you can overwrite your config file if you use Remote-SSH extension:
Go to -> Remote-SSH: Open SSH Configuration File...
And then you can change with the new remote path
{
    "host": "my-remote-server-PI-5",
    "hostName": "remote.server.com",
    "user": "username",
    "identityFile": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    "remotePath": "/path/to/your/default/directory"
}


I dont see a path there.  These come up as my general .ssh config files for the machine.  Seems like a settings file has to be around somewhere storing these.
